# Proguard Obfuscation failed in Jenkins build using Maven - can't read classes.jar

Tags: java, linux, maven, jenkins, proguard

I'm using Jenkins to build a Maven project on a Linux box and getting the following error:

> [proguard] Error: Can't read [/usr/lib/jvm/java-6-openjdk-amd64/Classes/classes.jar] (No such file or directory)

I have installed JDK and set the JAVA_HOME variable to:  /usr/lib/jvm/java-6-openjdk-amd64

However, if I take a look at the 'System Information' section of Jenkins I get two locations for java home:

> java.home: /usr/lib/jvm/java-6-openjdk-amd64/jre
>
> JAVA_HOME: /usr/lib/jvm/java-6-openjdk-amd64

When I run the project on MacOS the proguard plugin works perfectly so I know it has nothing to do with my project setup.  Something I'm missing in Jenkins or how Java is installed on my Server?

Comment: Locate the classes.jar under your java install location and specify your JAVA_HOME accordingly.

Comment: I cannot find the classes.jar anywhere?  If I run a: 'sudo apt-get install sun-java6-jdk' I get zero updates

Answer (score 0):

You are using proguard plugin?
Did you include the following in pom.xml?

```
<libs>
    <lib>${java.home}/Classes/classes.jar</lib>
</libs>
```

I guess, your development env is a mac box, and your jenkins is running in a linux box.
So that's the problem. 
The following settings could work in linux. And if you install Oracle Jdk 1.7 or 1.8 in mac, it will also ok.

```
<libs>
     <lib>${java.home}/lib/rt.jar</lib>
</libs>
```

My point is that the key of the problem is that the libs setting is from mac working with apple java6, and the jenkins is on linux.